# Adding a new row on Ajax call in a jQuery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am new to datatable and Javascript as well. I am trying to draw a table using datatable and my page keeps on checking the server for new data on a certain time interval using Ajax requests. If data is available I have to insert a new row as the first one in my existing datatable.

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
  $.post("/xxx/xxx/xxx/checkOrder",
  function(data){
    if(!(data === "")) {
      $('#order').dataTable().fnAddData(data);
    }
  });
}, 19000);
```

The server returns the following data:

```
["121111152591","New","abc","26-11-2012","2012-11-21","12:22","608.0"]
```

Now the problem is that the datatable inserts the first data string - 121111152591 as an individual column in datatable, like - col1 - [, col 2-1, col3-2 and so on.  Also in the case of multiple rows returned by JSON, the datatable fails to render. Can someone please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, I get confused with the problem. The objective is that each element of the array is a column, can you give an example of the result? Also, for many rows you should make a loop. Check this page: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/add_row.html

Comment: array is like arr[0] -> 1 row of table in a format given above. i.e.["121111152591","New","abc","26-11-2012","2012-11-21","12:22","608.0"] but on the page i am getting 1st element i.e. 121111152591 as complete row stripped off as individual column of datatable. i.e. 1 in column 1, 2 in colum 2 and 1 in column 3 and so on

Comment: Ok, sorry, I understand... Only the block "1211111" is rendered right? I mean for the total of columns? The rest gets ignored? Do you see an error message on the log?

Comment: Also, are you sure it is an array and not an object? If the server returns a response with 1 item, it will give you 1 array with N fields, and if the server returns a response with many items, it will give you an array of many arrays each one with N fields, right?

Comment: yes only 1211111 got rendered that too 1 digit in each column of my datatable. Server is returning me a String which i guess is an Object. But that should not be a problem because browser takes it as input stream of JSON objects. Same response structures(String) works for rendering table initially, It is only not working while adding new row dynamically.

Comment: Ok, but you have to be sure that the response is an array, not a object. And for the 2nd case, an array of arrays (where you have to make a loop).